# Android performance on switching Activity

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm working on an Android application with 3 Activities. 
They behave as three different tabs, so in its normal use, the user is likely to switch between one to another in a quick way.
To do that, I've always used the following code:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(currentclass.this, nextclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, at least two of the Activities may show a huge list of buttons viewed in a ScrollView View. By "huge" I mean 500 elements or so. Thus, as you can imagine, it takes too long to switch from one Activity to another one. Creating a new Activity every time instead of recovering an old one is mostly the problem.
Indeed, it is slightly faster to switch from some Activity to the previous visited Activity (which is the default backButton functionality) than to do it by the code above. I would like to know why exactly is it and how to benefit from it (using some flags on the Intent object).

Insomuch as even the backButton does not satisfy the performance I'm looking for, I would also like to hear about any suggestion which can improve my switching implementation.

Thank you!

Comment: you can implement view holders to increase performance of the loading of the lists from [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: startActivity(intent) calls the oncreate everytime but back button just destroy the open activity and old will be as it is ,its oncreate will not be called so it is fast

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using a scroll view.

The simple answer is to use a list instead. It has performance optimizations specifically to handle large numbers of items.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to increase performance here.

The view holder pattern mentioned by [SMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3193867/smr) is a great one to start with. Also make sure that you are converting views instead of making android manage 500 actual views, since this will make your UI take a long time to construct.

You can also use a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html) to load the data in the background so that the initial UI comes up and the list is updated as the loader populates the data. Does your list view really show 500 buttons on screen, or are there just 500 items, in which case you don't have to wait for all of them to load to fill up the screen?

You can switch to using [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) instead of Activities so that you are not recreating activities every time you switch tabs. Android tends to keep Fragments around more aggressively since it knows you may switch to them more quickly in a single activity.

You can also ensure that the data isn't flushed when an activity quits by attaching it to the [application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) instead, but this is not really recommended and doesn't stop the view churning.